# Asp.Net Core: Swagger-UI requests not working (are not relative)

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, relative-url

Hy

We're using Asp.Net Core to create a REST-Service with Swagger. We're hosting the service at a URL like this:

https://www.mywebsite.com/myservice

With the following code:

```
    applicationBuilder
        .UseSwagger()
        .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/1.0.0/swagger.json"",title);
            c.DisplayRequestDuration();
            c.OAuthClientId(clientId);
            c.OAuthRealm(redirectUri);
            c.OAuthAppName("App");
        });
```

...the Swagger-UI is correctly loading at:

https://www.mywebsite.com/myservice/swagger/

But when I try to do a Request over the UI with the Execute-Button, I got a 404, because the UI tries to do the request without the /myservice/ in the URL:

https://www.mywebsite.com/v1/cars

instead of

https://www.mywebsite.com/myservice/v1/cars

How do I have to correctly configure the service, so that the Swagger UI Calls are also working?

Hint:

This should be done in a generic way (like the ../ of the UI), because we will deploy the service on different environments, so the www.mywebsite.com is not the same on each environment.

Thanks for your help!

Regards,

Peter

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Both `Swagger` and `Swagger UI` need to be configured with relative paths. For example, if I wanted the UI to be accessible at the root of the app (whatever that might be) and the JSON endpoint at `swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json`, my configuration would look like this:

```
// register the services
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {    
  c.SwaggerDoc("latest", new Info { Title = "Web API", Version = "latest" }); 
}
```

...

```
app.UseMvc();

// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwagger(c => {
    c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
}

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
// specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/latest/swagger.json", "DynaFile Web API");
     c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; //To serve the Swagger UI at the app's root
}
```

And obviously my controllers don't need to know my app name either. For example:

```
[Route("~/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
   ....
}
```